# Manually customizing a header's colour

Tags: header-footer, color

I would like to change the background colour of a page and necessarily also the text colour. While that is no problem for the main text, the header (and footer) text colour needs to be changes separately. Consider this minimal-but not working-example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
A black and white page.
\newpage
\pagecolor{green}
%%%%%%%%
{\color{white}%
\chapter*{A white and green page}
}
%%%%%%%%
\thispagestyle{myheadings}
\makeatletter
\global\let\originaloddhead\@oddhead
\global\let\originalevenhead\@evenhead
\renewcommand{\@oddhead}{{\protect\color{white}\originaloddhead}}
\renewcommand{\@evenhead}{{\protect\color{white}\originalevenhead}}
\makeatother
\markboth{header text}{header text}
%%%%%%%%
{\color{white}%
Some text.
}
%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\nopagecolor
\makeatletter
\let\@oddhead\originaloddhead
\let\@evenhead\originalevenhead
\makeatother
Another black and white page.
\end{document}
```

does not work but gives a black header.

What does work is

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ps@inverted}{%
  \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{%
    {\protect\color{white}\small\upshape\hfil\rightmark\hskip\tw@ em\thepage}}%
  \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{%
    {\protect\color{white}\small\upshape\thepage\hskip\tw@ em\leftmark\hfill}}%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A black and white page.
\newpage
\pagecolor{black}%
{\color{white}%
\chapter*{A white and black page}
\thispagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{header text}{header text}
\thispagestyle{inverted}%
Some text.
}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{myheadings}
\nopagecolor
Another black and white page.
\end{document}
```

but I would like to know *why*  the first attempt does not work and possibly how to fix it. OK, [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr), [nccfancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccfancyhdr) or similar packages would probably do the trick, but I don't just want a solution (I got one, see above), but to understand *how things work*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `{` group starting just before the `\color{white}` which finishes at the end of the page. It keeps the colour change local but also your definition of `\originaloddhead`
is discarded at the end of the group. You would need

```
\global\let\originaloddhead\@oddhead
\global\let\originalevenhead\@evenhead
```

Comment: Ah, yes, smacking my head! +1! I corrected the question. But also with that the colour change for the header is not regarded?

Comment: move the `\newpage` up a line so the previous page is output within the scope not just after it. You can get away with this as you have forced page breaks, in general what you _should_ do is define a new page style which is like the old one but with coloured header then use `\thispagestyle{colouredhead}` and latex will take care if using the right header on the right page.

Comment: OK, moving the `\newpage` into the group makes sense, but when I tested this, it had no effect (header still black). To make things easier I limited the `text white` just to the text, but that does not work either. As you can see from the second (working) example, I defined a new pagestyle, and that indeed works. For just 1 single page with header, `\chapter*` and 2 lines of text this is probably overkill, but I'm using that. I'm just curious why the other approach did not work. When I make a mistake here, I'll probably also make it somewhere else. (And I'd like to understand how things work.)